# Is there any advantages of the mounting side (left or right) of the motor in a FWD vehicle?

Tags: engine-theory, automotive-design

Almost every FWD I have dealt with has the engine on the left side and the transmission on the right. Hondas with the D17 Engine has it the opposite which made me curious. Does the mounting side of the engine signify anything? specially since that the crank shaft naturally spins clock wise so does that design provide any advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: Your use of left/right is ambiguous - is this with you facing the engine bay or facing the direction of travel?

Comment: I am sorry I guess I reversed it, I mean when you are facing the engine.

Comment: It could just be that the first to do this (Mini 1959 Sir A. Issigonis) had the engine on the left and, given the general layout of carburettor / exhaust etc most manufacturers have followed that layout, unless they had other design constraints etc to work to / with.